# Add different first view to GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to have in my `GridView` first item different from the others. The gridview's adapter can be either adapter extending from `CursorAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter`. It is depending on from where are images path taken - db, or arraylist.

For now everything works fine, but I want to have first element different from the rest. The first element, no matter what is the adapter, has to be empty element which will be button from where I can add extra elements. The image in first element has to be from resource, while the images for rest of the elements are form uri.

Also, there is `emptyView` of this `gridView` set. I've tried adding first element into arraylist at the very beginning, but then empty view is not shown. Also, I don't know how it will work with content from DB. To be honest I haven't got any more idea, and also I cannot find anything in Google.

Do you know any way I can add this first view?

I need it to work on API10 and above.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1. in the adapter, you can check if position is 0 than inflate the other view.
2. More complex but seems like better one for you is to override (Assuming you are using ArrayAdapter) the methods:

   getItemViewType(int position)
   getViewTypeCount()

You can find nice and friendly example [here](http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/)

--- Edit ---

To show your empty view you need to be sure that:

1. Your View inflated correctly.
2. you called mGridview.setEmptyView(view);
3. There are no items to show in the adapter, that means that in your grid view adapter the function getCount() returns 0. Note that this function should be implement with the correct logic after you implements the 2 methods I've mentioned above.

Comment: OK, I'll check it. About emptyView - yes, exactly. Is this method with ovveriding good also for cursor adapter? I am using both.

Comment: You can use the overrided method in CursorAdapter, don't really sure if they can help you there but you may try...never done it before. see my edited answer for the empty view